# Programmatically apply and edit a windows explorer template?

Tags: c#, shell, powershell, windows-explorer

I'm looking for way to automate some explorer configuration (like ones found here: [Customize the Five Windows Folder Templates](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/)).

I want to:

1. update windows explorer folder template "Document" to add two columns
2. apply recursively this template to a webdav folder

I have found nearly no documentation.

I tried to use procmon.exe to intercept where these settings are located, but I didn't find something relevant.

I tried to script the shell object:

```
$shell = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $shell.Namespace("http://myserver/webdav")
# $folder.???? nothing relevant
$self = $folder.self
# $self.???? nothing relevant too
```

I explored the registry in hope to find something, but I didn't.

What are my options? I even don't know where these settings are located.

If possible, the solution should use a scripting language (vbs or powershell). Or if absolutely needed, a C# program may be possible... If only I know where to start

**[edit]** procmon shows that the reg key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.AddColumns\` is read when adding the column. However, I don't know what's the meaning of this registry section.

Comment: Might be some useful information for you here: http://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/desktopini.html

Comment: it's a good start. I can apply the default template of a folder, but I don't understand how to setup columns (the sample in the link has no effect)

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm quite interested in this my self

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat: unfortunately not